# MariaDB pivot tables - rows to colums . Query

Tags: mariadb, pivot-table

I have this table in MariaDB:

| DATE | NAME | MARK |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-02-01 | ALEX | 7 |
| 2021-02-01 | JOHN | 5 |
| 2021-02-01 | FRANK | 4 |
| 2021-02-02 | EVA | 8 |
| 2021-02-02 | ALICIA | 5 |

How can I get a result similar to this:

| DATE | ALEX | JOHN | FRANK | EVA | ALICIA |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-02-01 | 7 | 5 | 4 |  |  |
| 2021-02-02 |  |  |  | 8 | 5 |

It is Possible in MariaDB?

Comment: Use dynamic SQL in stored procedure.

Comment: That's a sql anti-pattern. While rules are made to be broken, in principle it indicates you're trying to do something the wrong way, or in the wrong place (do this in presentation layers, not in data layers)

Comment: Seriously consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 1):

Create procedure

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE pivot (tablename VARCHAR(64),
                        groupname VARCHAR(64),
                        pivotname VARCHAR(64),
                        valuename VARCHAR(64))
BEGIN
SELECT CONCAT('CREATE VIEW to_columnslist AS\n',
              'SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(\'`\', `', pivotname,'`, \'` VARCHAR(255) path \\\'$."\', ', pivotname,', \'"\\\'\') line\n',
              'FROM ', tablename)
INTO @sql;
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DROP PREPARE stmt;
SELECT CONCAT(
'SELECT to_json.`', groupname,'`, parsed.*', '\n',
'FROM (SELECT `', groupname,'`, JSON_OBJECTAGG(`', pivotname,'`, `', valuename,'`) json_data', '\n',
'      FROM `', tablename,'`', '\n',
'      GROUP BY `', groupname,'`) to_json', '\n',
'CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE( json_data,', '\n',
'                       "$" COLUMNS ( ', 
GROUP_CONCAT(line SEPARATOR ',\n                                     '),
' ) ) parsed'
) sql_text
INTO @sql
FROM to_columnslist;
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DROP PREPARE stmt;
DROP VIEW to_columnslist;
END
```

and use it.

See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=18fb41d1722d17a7cc8f3ea837679ea0)

Comment: Thank you very much!!! Can i use secondary index for example date?

Comment: Hi! it s works only with mysql 8? I got Mariadb and doesn t works. Br,Alessandro

Comment: @AlessandroLaRagione You have tagged your question as MySQL-relative and have not specified its version - so I must assume that you use the most recent MySQL version. MariaDB (any version) and MySQL (prior to 8.0.14) cannot use this code.

Comment: Sorry this Is my fault.

Comment: @AlessandroLaRagione I'll investigate. This will take some time.

Comment: @AlessandroLaRagione https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7d06b1257fcc50077eb304f1e8c2f52d The problem source was in `NAME VARCHAR(6)` - the value `'John Jr.'` is longer than 6 symbols.

Comment: Ok i found problem but i don t know how to solve It. I add varchar(60) 'verify' field. So if i add an other field procedure doesn t works. Can you help me? BR,Alessandro

Comment: @AlessandroLaRagione I cannot now, because I cannot guess your data. Create a fiddle with your real structure and data sample.

Comment: Ok if i have more than 10 values at same date It doesn t works...

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=334367b6707e072d76c5ff3802efdd3f

Comment: @AlessandroLaRagione Now the source of the problem is server settings. By default the value of `@@group_concat_max_len` system variable is 1024, so the query text is truncated. Increase its value.

Comment: Ok i have increased value SET GLOBAL group_concat_max_len = 100000000.  But It doesn t works

Comment: @AlessandroLaRagione https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a5b399518942955702a5e05da11b6617

Comment: Hi! It works! Thank you! It possible to have a result in a view? And It possible for example only update view only with new record? If i execute procedure each time It take a lot of time.

Comment: @AlessandroLaRagione *It possible to have a result in a view?* You have a query text which gives needed result - nothing prevents to create a view with this query text. *update view only with new record?* Store the timestamp of view creation in some service table and compare it with maximal `updated_at` value, if the view is older then re-create it.

Comment: Thank you. I never used stored procedure...for me Is forse time....so...Can you help me?

Comment: Ok i need to insert a where in pivot procedure...I have tried but i have some problems....

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4d81e7d6fdae9d538cd3d330a1024a67

Comment: Nobody Can help me? I Need filter by tagname and timestamp stored procedure

Comment: Akina, Can you help me?

Comment: @AlessandroLaRagione, the comment section is not intended for follow up questions.

Comment: If more than one concurrent client tries to use this solution, they will conflict. Each of them will try to create the `to_columnslist` view, but all but the first will lose and get an error.

Comment: @BillKarwin Ok it possible to pass table view name in Procedure and don't use to_columnslist ?

Comment: If you are running an old version (without JSON), see http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pivot