# SQL query - stumped me during an interview

Tags: mysql, sql

I was asked a basic SQL question during an interview and I was stumped by it. I couldnt come up with a solution.
The table structure and data are given below :

| Student ID | Subject | Marks |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Maths | 20 |
| 1 | Bio | 30 |
| 2 | Maths | 40 |
| 2 | Bio | 50 |
| 3 | Maths | 60 |
| 3 | Bio | 70 |

The output should be :

| Student ID | Maths | Bio |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20 | 30 |
| 2 | 40 | 50 |
| 3 | 60 | 70 |

What will be the query to get the desired output?

Comment: I ll do that. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `group by` and conditional sums:

```
SELECT `Student ID`, SUM(CASE Subject WHEN 'Maths' THEN Marks END) Maths,
                     SUM(CASE Subject WHEN 'Bio'   THEN Marks END) Bio
FROM   mytable
GROUP BY `Student ID`;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT Student_id, t1.mark Maths, t2.Mark Bio
FROM table t1
JOIN table t2 USING (Student_id)
WHERE t1.Subject = 'Maths'
  AND t2.Subject = 'Bio'
```

For dynamic subjects list use, for example, https://stackoverflow.com/a/66136355/10138734