# MySQL procedure for MariaDB

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mariadb

I have this procedure that works without any problem under MySQL:
[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=18fb41d1722d17a7cc8f3ea837679ea0)

*solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66136355/13174083)*

I tried to add it to MariaDB 10.5 from within phpmyadmin - exactly like this, I just added `DELIMITER ;;` in the first line and `END;;` and `DELIMITER ;` at the end.

After that MySQL returned an empty result set and everything looks ok, but only when calling the procedure there are already errors like [these](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=18fb41d1722d17a7cc8f3ea837679ea0)

I'm guessing that the problem occurs with the separators that make up the two SELECTs, but my ideas to fix it so far have yielded nothing.

Comment: MariaDB have no JSON_TABLE() function or something similar.

Comment: @Akina yea, actually, in MariaDB JSON_TABLE is available since version 10.6.0. Do you perhaps know how to improve this procedure so that it works on MariaDB without JSON?

Comment: Do the same using regular JSON and/or string functions. In MariaDB 10.5 you may use recursive CTE for iterative structure parsing and dynamic query text generation.