# MySQL query to add columns dynamically (unpivotting dynamically)

Tags: mysql, sql, unpivot

i have a table like :

```
ID  snapdate      createdate
123  2022-10-03     2022-12-29
123  2022-10-10     2022-02-01
246  2022-10-03     2022-02-04
246  2022-10-10     2022-1-11
```

i want to make snapdate as columns and corresponding values will be populated as below:

```
ID   createdate(for 2022-10-03)     createdate(for 2022-10-10)
123     2022-12-29                     2022-02-01
246     2022-02-04                     2022-1-11
```

i tried it in excel till now using vlookup but want to automate it using SQL. Any assistance please let me know.

Comment: See, for example, https://stackoverflow.com/a/66136355/10138734 PS. Shown date format is not correct for MySQL.

Comment: Thanks Akina,,, i corrected the date format..and the example you shared i think is bit different but close though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your current sample data, the final query you're probably aiming for is something like this:

```
SELECT ID,
       MAX(CASE WHEN snapdate='2022-10-03' THEN createdate END) AS '2022-10-03',
       MAX(CASE WHEN snapdate='2022-10-10' THEN createdate END) AS '2022-10-10'
FROM mytable
GROUP BY ID;
```

For the *dynamic* requirement here, you can try using prepared statement.

In this example, I'll structure the query using two variables for better understanding and I'll include another option where everything is in a single query.

Variables:

```
SET @columns := NULL; /*for the columns*/
SET @sql := NULL; /*for the final query*/
```

The first thing here is to create the columns and assigning it to `@columns`:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(
       DISTINCT CONCAT("MAX(CASE WHEN snapdate='", snapdate,"' THEN createdate END) AS '",snapdate,"'")
        ORDER BY snapdate) INTO @columns
FROM mytable;
```

Then, combine that variable to make the final query and assign to `@sql` variable:

```
SELECT CONCAT("SELECT ID,",@columns," 
     FROM mytable
     GROUP BY ID") INTO @sql;
```

Prepare, execute then deallocate the statement:

```
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

The prepared statement below is the same thing as above but only using a single variable and a single query to create:

```
SET @sql := NULL;

SELECT CONCAT("SELECT ID,",GROUP_CONCAT(
       DISTINCT CONCAT("MAX(CASE WHEN snapdate='", snapdate,"' THEN createdate END) AS '",snapdate,"'")
        ORDER BY snapdate)," 
     FROM mytable
     GROUP BY ID") INTO @sql
FROM mytable;

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

[More tests in this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/mMieh2yU)

Comment: Thanks FanoFN..I appreciate the effort for proving the solution.Let me check with it.Thanks Again